# formly Default value in dynamic options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I use angular js formly to create my web forms.
my problem is when is use select with dynamic options the defaultValue property dos not work. but when is set static data to options it is work.
how can i set default value (selected option) in formly when i get options from remote server ?

```
{
className: 'col-sm-3',
key: 'cityId',
type: 'select',
templateOptions: {
    placeholder: 'City',
    required: true,
    label: 'City',
    valueProp: 'id',
    labelProp: 'name',
    options: $scope.cityCombo
},

defaultValue: '3209C692-B8D4-4AB0-9F40-008A7C4644F9',
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `controller` option for this field.

This is example for getting all categories for selection options and setting value of select field dynamically according to current product's category:

```
  {
    key: 'category',
    type: 'select',
    wrapper: "loading",
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Category',
      options: [],
      valueProp: 'name',
      labelProp: 'name'
    },
    controller: function($scope, productsFactory, $routeParams) {
      $scope.to.loading = productsFactory.getCategories().then(function(response){
        $scope.to.options = response.data.categories;
        // note, the line above is shorthand for:
        // $scope.options.templateOptions.options = data;
        productsFactory.getProduct($routeParams.id).then(function(response) {
          $scope.model.category = response.data.product.category.name;
        });
        return response;
      });
    }
  }
```

And in your case it should be something like this:

```
{
  className: 'col-sm-3',
  key: 'cityId',
  type: 'select',
  templateOptions: {
    placeholder: 'City',
    required: true,
    label: 'City',
    valueProp: 'id',
    labelProp: 'name',
    options: $scope.cityCombo
  },
  // defaultValue: '',

  controller: function($scope /*inject*/) {
    // some code 
    $scope.model.cityId = cityId; // dynamically set cityId
    // some code 
    };
  }
}
```